# Locale - Only for internationalization?

Tags: localization, internationalization, locale, resourcebundle

I need a locale-like functionality, for purposes other than internationalization.

For example, I'd like to use the resource-bundle mechanism and have different resource bundles for different customization, e.g. one file for client A, another file for client B and another default file (for values that don't exist in the specific client's file). The only way to do it would be "forcing" a locale for each client, and I don't want to do that.

Is there a different structure for this kind of things?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see any reason why you could not deal with customization as kind of localization in a simple case. A locale is ultimately a description of user preferences. The reason why it is mostly based on language and possibly country is just that these are the most common things that tend to cause differences that can be handled in software.

Most systems of locale identifiers used these have some way of presenting “variants” with some extension mechanism. In ResourceBundle, this appears to be the “variant” argument.

The main problem is that the systems of locales are primitive in the sense that they presume a hierarchic system rather than orthogonal. That is, you could define a locale for en-US-x-A (to use BCP 47 locale ids) for English, US, company A, but if you need a locale for employees of A preferring Canadian French, it would have to be fr-CA-x-A, and for this you would need to copy the A-specific settings.

So I would conclude that using locales for customization is OK at least if you do *not* need localization in the normal sense (different languages, different countries).

Comment: The ResourceBundle mechanism has a few problems - First, it can only support 3 levels of hierarchy (language, country and variant) and I need more. Second, it forces me to capitalize the 2nd level locale, which isn't that big of a deal, but nevertheless frustrating. Therefore, I'm seeking something else. Seems like I'm gonna have to implement it on my own.